# Shared memory and Cloudfoundry container issue with php exec using boost interprocess library

Tags: php, c++, cloud-foundry, boost-interprocess

We have our custom php-buildpack running in cloudfoundry container.
Issue is that apache start -> php-fpm (here shared memory code run fine). php-fpm exec() php scripts which start -> php-cli (it core dump on shared memory code).

For shared memory we use boost-1.56.0
Example :-

```
<?php
 exec("php  anotherscript.php");
 ?>
```

## anotherscript.php

```
<?php
  custom extention call i.e c/c++ code 
?>
```

==========
sample.cpp  (create shared memoory using boost)

```
permissions perms;
perms.set_unrestricted();
managed_shared_memory segment(create_only, SharedDataShmSegmentName, segmentSize, 0, perms);
interprocess_sharable_mutex *mutex= segment.construct<interprocess_sharable_mutex>(SharedDataShmMutexName)();
```

It gives core dump as - 
`Signal 11 (segmentation fault)(core dumped)`

We are suspecting child exec() will have less privileges than master process or child exec() will not have shared memory permission like CAP_IPC_LOCK capabilities.

Is there issue with Cloudfoundry container child process created by exec() with shared memory (boost - 1.56.0) ?

Comment: How much shared memory are you trying to allocate per container?

Comment: What ever default available for shared memory. For main memory we give memory: 200M  in manifest.yml.

Answer (score 1):

Your Cloud Foundry administrator needs to enable privileged containers otherwise CF drops `CAP_IPC_LOCK` capability. See https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/container-security.html

Also shared memory is a "special" memory. For example Docker allows only 64MB of shared memory by default. Of course, it can be increased by special parameter `--shm-size=""` - see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

But CF doesn't use Docker, but Garden-runC which may need special parameter for shared memory size.

Comment: It is working fine for master process i.e php-fpm , but when exec() call it start php-cli as child process and it core dump there.